# TypeError in Google Analytics Chart web components

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, polymer

I'm using Google Polymer elements to create a Google Analytics dashboard. It seems to work fine but throws an error with a reference to the following in the google-analytics-chart file.

The error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…)

The reference:

```
/**
 * The analytics api erroneously return some values as strings that are
 * supposed to be numbers. This function fixes that.
 * @param {Object} dataTable - The dataTable data.
 */
function ensureProperDataTableTypes(dataTable) {
  for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = dataTable.rows[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < row.c.length; j++) {
      if (dataTable.cols[j].type === 'number') {
        row.c[j].v = Number(row.c[j].v);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the provided code by Google to create the graphs. Like this example:

```
<google-analytics-chart
metrics="ga:sessions"
dimensions="ga:country"
sort="-ga:sessions"
max-results="5"
chart-type="column">
</google-analytics-chart>
```

Do you have any idea to what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can modify temporary the code just to check the content of the array before iterating it, and take a look at the console to now who/when is causing the exception:

```
function ensureProperDataTableTypes(dataTable) {
  if (dataTable && Array.isArray(datatable.rows)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.rows.length; i++) {   //The call to length will cause your exception is rows is not an array
      var row = dataTable.rows[i];
      if(Array.isArray(row.c)){
        for (var j = 0; j < row.c.length; j++) { //The call to length will cause your exception if c is not an array
          if (dataTable.cols[j].type === 'number') {
            row.c[j].v = Number(row.c[j].v);
          }
        }  
      }
      else{
        console.error("Row should contain an array of cols");
      }
    }
  } else{
    console.error("parameter should contain an array of rows");
  }
}
```